# Selecting css element on this site in scrapy (python)

Tags: python, scrapy

For some reason my CSS selector doesn't return anything on this site. Any idea why?

```
import scrapy

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.toppstiles.co.uk/fixing-finishing/tools-accessories/mixing-drilling/drilling/rubi-drill-bit-diamond-50mm",
        # "https://books.toscrape.com/"
    ]
    

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.css('h5').get())
```

What I don't get is why CSS selectors work on other sites and I can also get the `head` element. Am I being blocked? Can I get around it?

Comment: `scrapy` doesn't execute JavaScript. You need to use Selenium

Comment: how can I see that something is JS?

Comment: You look at the HTML with View Source. If it's not in the HTML, it must be added by JS.

Comment: You can disable the javascript in your browser. In Chrome, open the Inspect Window. Then Press Ctrl+Shift+P and write "Disable Javascript". That will disable javascript rendering. Then refresh the page keeping the Inspector sidebar open.